# Dockerized Spring Boot app can't load file in war

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, war

I dockerized my Spring Boot App. There is a piece of code that loads a bin file (eg, my-bin-file.bin) and build a model out of it. Whenever I run the standalone app (through run on IntelliJ) it can find the file and build the model. However, when I run it through the Dockerfile, it can't find it and fails.

*Dockerfile*

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/services-*.war /app/services.war
CMD ["java", "-jar", "services.war"]
```

*File Resource*

```
root
 |-- src
   |-- java
     |-- packages and java files
   |-- resource
     |-- binFolder
       |-- my-bin-file.bin
```

*Bin Loader*

```
public class BinLoader {
    public static String[] loadBinFile() throws IOException {
        String folder = BinLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("binFolder").getFile();
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(folder + "my-bin-file.bin")) {
        // build model   
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the war file, and it's packaged in there in the expected path. It's inside `/WEB-INF/classes/binFolder/my-bin-file.bin`

The InputStream fails with `NullException`.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are using a `FileInputStream` which won't work as it isn't a `java.util.File` in the sense that it is not a file on the actual file path. Instead, as you are already using Spring, use a `ClassPathResource` and use the `getInputStream` to load the file. That will work in both cases. something like `new ClassPathResource("/binFolder/my-bin-file.bin").getInputStream()`.

Comment: That did the trick. If you could just copy over that over to a reply, I'll accept the answer. Thanks for your insight. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of the `FileInputStream`. It will use a `java.io.File` to try to read the referenced resource, however a `java.io.File` expects the referenced resource to be an actual file on a file system. This is the case when you are running from Intellij but not when you are running from a jar or war.

To fix utilize Spring to load the resource from you from the classpath and obtain the `InputStream`. To make it easier you can use the `ClassPathResource` to directly access it. This will work in both cases, running from Intellij and as jar/war.

```java
public static String[] loadBinFile() throws IOException {
  String resource = "/binFolder/my-bin-file.bin";
  try (InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource(resource).getInputStream()) {
    // build model   
    ...
  }
}
```